# Created an unwanted branch in git, want to get rid of it

Tags: git, git-branch

JIRA created a branch for a feature I was working on, but I don't want it. I'd like to move all the changes I've made so far back to the master branch and simply remove the feature branch altogether. Can anyone help me?

[image: I just want one simple master branch on top, where the ANDROIDAPP-137 is now.]

Comment: How many changes are on your feature branch that you want to bring over?

Comment: do you want just to `merge` your new branch with master and delete that branch ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should merge or rebase now, reading some documentation on both atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's make sure what this is going to do:

1. move your commits on branch `ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow` to `master`
2. completely remove (locally and remote) `ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow` branch

first get back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

now get the work from your branch; rebase onto that branch:

```
git rebase ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow
```

now your commits should be on both `master` and `ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow` branch, you can check with:

```
git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline
```

so you can remove the jira branch:

```
git branch -D ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow
```

and remove it remotely:

```
git push origin :ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow
```

Comment: I'm not rebasing on remote... his graph shows clearly he has all the changes on the local `ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow` branch

Answer (score 1):

**If** I'm reading your log correctly, it seems all you need to do is a rebase/merge and you'll be good to go:

```
git checkout master
git rebase ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow
git branch -d ANDROIDAPP-137-actions-are-slow
```

If rebase doesn't work, do a merge instead.

For more on git branching [check out the documentation on it.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branch-Management)

Comment: and what is different with my answer (which also proposes to delete the remote branch) ?

Comment: @ChrisMaes - Nothing. I have a feeling we submitted our answers at the same time. When I answered, there was nothing else here.